# Metro App RichEditBox Default ForegroundColor

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

The `WinRT` `RichEditBox` `ForegroundColor` is `Black` by default.

How do I change this to a custom color?

This is what I tried...

```
// Set default ForegroundColor
ITextCharacterFormat defaultCharacterFormat = 
    redBody.Document.GetDefaultCharacterFormat();

defaultCharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Colors.Blue;

redBody.Document.SetDefaultCharacterFormat(defaultCharacterFormat);
redBody.Document.ApplyDisplayUpdates();
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a XAML [RichEditBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.aspx), then the Foreground property should work for you, e.g. `<RichEditBox Foreground="Violet" />`.

Comment: I feel really silly now. It's amazing how sometimes the most obvious solutions slip our minds.

Comment: It's nice when the solution is simple and concise :)